# Beast SSL Connection Graceful Shutdown

Tags: c++, https, openssl, boost-beast

I am implementing an HTTPS client that tries to read information from the server. During its work the shutdown can be requested. It can be expresses in the following code:

```
        http::async_read( stream_, buffer_, res_,
                          beast::bind_front_handler(
                                  &session::on_read,
                                  shared_from_this()));
        beast::get_lowest_layer( stream_ ).cancel();
```

As soon as the read is cancelled (`on_read` is called with operation cancel error) I call

```
stream_.async_shutdown([t = shared_from_this()] ( beast::error_code ec ) {
            t->on_shutdown(ec);
        });
```

The shutdown finishes with the following error:

```
application data after close notify
```

The question is whether it is safe to ignore this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore this error. It happens if a server sends data concurrently - started sending an application data chunk asynchronousely right before has received close notify.

```
stream_.async_shutdown([t = shared_from_this()] ( beast::error_code ec ) {
    if (ec ...)  // add proper condition here
        ec = beast::error_code(success);
    t->on_shutdown(ec);
});
```

I would also add some flag to session and set it before cancel, so `session::on_read` is not unexpected, can be ignored after shutdown.

Comment: Did not quite understand about the flag. I call ```async_shutdown``` when I am already in the ```on_read``` function, so why there can be additional calls of ```on_read``` that should be ignored?

Comment: *application data after close notify* - as you can see, async tls shutdown does not guarantee not receiving one more `session::on_read`.

Comment: But does not calling ```cancel``` guarantee that it will not be called?

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. I thought you call shutdown directly w/o cancel. I'm not sure, if cancel guaranties no further on_read call with operation cancel error. It can cause double async_shutdown call, that is not desired.